# How to assert ast.TypeSpec to int type in Golang?

Tags: go, reflection

I have following code for Golang docs parsing. "ts" is ast.TypeSpec. I can check StructType and etc. But, ts.Type is "int". How can I assert for int and other basic type?

```
ts, ok := d.Decl.(*ast.TypeSpec)
switch ts.Type.(type) {
case *ast.StructType:
    fmt.Println("StructType")
case *ast.ArrayType:
    fmt.Println("ArrayType")
case *ast.InterfaceType:
    fmt.Println("InterfaceType")
case *ast.MapType:
    fmt.Println("MapType")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The types in the AST represent the syntax used to declare the type and not the actual type. For example:

```
type t struct { }

var a int          // TypeSpec.Type is *ast.Ident
var b struct { }   // TypeSpec.Type is *ast.StructType
var c t            // TypeSpec.Type is *ast.Ident, but c variable is a struct type
```

I find it's helpful to print example ASTs when trying to understand how different syntax is represented. [Run this program to see an example](https://play.golang.org/p/Hof55EHNsu).

This code will check for ints in most cases, but does not do so reliably:

```
if id, ok := ts.Type.(*ast.Ident); ok {
    if id.Name == "int" {
        // it might be an int
    }
}
```

The code is not correct for the following cases:

```
type myint int
var a myint          // the underlying type of a is int, but it's not declared as int

type int anotherType 
var b int            // b is anotherType, not the predeclared int type
```

To reliably find the actual types in the source, use the [go/types](https://godoc.org/go/types) package.  [A tutorial on the package is available](https://github.com/golang/example/tree/master/gotypes).

Comment: In this case, I think we can use bt := fmt.Sprintf("%s",ts.Type), I am not sure which one is better.

Comment: It's usually better to use methods and fields to inspect the AST than whatever fmt.Sprintf prints out.